# vvvv/SVG not rendering text

Tags: c#, svg, vvvv

I'm trying to use vvvv/SVG library (https://github.com/vvvv/SVG , current version) in my C# project. I've managed to do some simple drawing, however ended on strange behaviour when rendering text.

Following code adds text element to SvgDocument, but no text is rendered in bitmap.

```
        this.SvgDoc = new SvgDocument();
        this.SvgDoc.Width = new SvgUnit(400);
        this.SvgDoc.Height = new SvgUnit(400);

        SvgText txt = new SvgText("TEST");
        txt.X.Add(new SvgUnit(100));
        txt.Y.Add(new SvgUnit(100));
        //txt.FontFamily = "Arial";
        txt.FontSize = new SvgUnit(15);
        txt.Fill = new SvgColourServer(Color.Black);
        this.SvgDoc.Children.Add(txt);

        var bmp2 = this.SvgDoc.Draw();
        this.PBoxRes.Image = bmp2;
```

If I try to add eg. circle node, it renders ok. Text will not render until I store svg to string, parse it with SvgDocument.FromSvg() and render bitmap after that. That's working, however too slow with larger SVG and minor changes. Is there something I can do to make the text renderable imediatelly, without reparsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add this:

```
SvgContentNode newContent = new SvgContentNode();
newContent.Content = "Text";
txt.Nodes.Add(newContent);
```

Comment: Very good! You don't happen to know the answer to my similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34839802/alter-gradient-in-svg-using-svg-net

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across the same issue and it took me some time to figure it out. It seems that an `SvgText` needs children in order to be included in the XML of the resulting .svg file.

For me, including the text as a nested content node did the trick:

```
new SvgDocument
{
    Width = 100,
    Height = 100,
    FontSize = 10,
    Nodes =
    {
        new SvgText
        {
            Nodes = {new SvgContentNode {Content = "my text"}},
            X = {10},
            Y = {10}
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to add text, but it creates the XML tag `<text x="10" y="10">my text</text>` in the resulting .svg file, which seems correct to me.